# put multiple values into json_encode

Tags: php

I am using an array with multiple SQL Queries then using a foreach loop to run the queries:

```
foreach($sql as $query) {
    $rs=mysql_query($query, $conn);
    if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0){
        while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
            $json_arr["id"] = $result['sequence'];
            $json_arr["value"] = $result['company'];
            $json_arr["label"] = $result['company'];
            array_push($display_json, $json_arr);
        }
    } else {
        $json_arr["id"] = "#";
        $json_arr["value"] = "";
        $json_arr["label"] = "No Result Found!";
        array_push($display_json, $json_arr);
    }
}
```

i then need to use `json_encode` and print the results like:

```
$jsonWrite = json_encode($display_json); //encode that search data
print $jsonWrite;
```

how can i do one `json_encode` for all the query results?

Comment: Merge all the arrays together and json encode that one.

Comment: how do i merge arrays?

Comment: The code you have should work fine. What do you get and what is the desired result?

Comment: because its doing a loop, its printing multiple json results per loop

Comment: Move the first array_push command to outside of the while loop, it will then only be executed once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($sql as $query) {
    $rs=mysql_query($query, $conn);
    if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0){
        while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
            $json_arr["id"] = $result['sequence'];
            $json_arr["value"] = $result['company'];
            $json_arr["label"] = $result['company'];

        }
        array_push($display_json, $json_arr);
    } else {
        $json_arr["id"] = "#";
        $json_arr["value"] = "";
        $json_arr["label"] = "No Result Found!";
        array_push($display_json, $json_arr);
    }
}
```

Moving the first array_push to outside of the while loop, as above, will prevent the repetition you're seeing.